# How to give explicitly input and output to Snakemake file?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pipeline, snakemake

So I have a pipeline written in shell which loops over three folders and then an inside loop which loops over files inside the folder.

For next step, I have a snakemake file, which takes an input folder and output folder. For trial run I gave the folder path inside the snakemake file.
**So I was wondering is there any way I can give input and output folder path explicitly.**

For e.g.
`snakemake --cores 30 -s trial.snakemake /path/to/input /path/to/output`

Since I want to change the input and output according to the main loop.

I tried `import sys` and using `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` inside the snakemake file but its not working.

Below is the snippet of my pipeline, it takes three folder for now, ABC_Samples, DEF_Samples, XYZ_Samples

```
for folder in /path/to/*_Samples
do
  folderName=$(basename $folder _Samples)
  mkdir -p /path/to/output/$fodlerName
  for files in $folder/*.gz
  do
    /
     do something
    /
  done
  snakemake --cores 30 -s trial.snakemake /path/to/output/$fodlerName /path/to/output2/
done
```

But the above doesn't work. So is there any way I can do this. I am really new to snakemake.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient way could be to incorporate the folder structure explicitly inside your Snakefile. For example, you could use the content of a parameter, e.g. `example_path`, inside the Snakefile and then pass it via [`config`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html):

```sh
snakemake --config example_path_in=/path/to/input example_path_out=/path/to/output
```

Comment: but the thing is $fodlerName will be change as the loop goes, so how can I pass that to the snakemake file. It cant read the shell variable right?

Comment: You could stick this into a bash loop and replace `example_path_in` with the bash variable (e.g. `example_path_in=$folderName`). However, this is not efficient because it doesn't let snakemake exploit parallelisation opportunities... a better way would be to re-write the snakefile, but from your question it's not clear what is inside the snakefile.

Comment: Actually my pipeline processes a biological data and in that one process is little bit complicated but for that i got a ready made snakemake file. I have very less knowledge of snakemake, I am learning now.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :)
I guess I can work around it.